# No redefine Interface, No define method, class - is it possible?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and java. I have some questions about the code interpretation. This is part of company SDK.

```
public class RECOBeaconManager {

   private static long d;    
   private static long e;
   private static RECOBeaconManager f;
   private Context g;
   private Messenger h = null;
   private Messenger i = null;
   private CopyOnWriteArrayList<RECOBeaconRegion> j;
   private CopyOnWriteArrayList<RECOBeaconRegion> k;
   protected RECOMonitoringListener a;
   protected RECORangingListener b;
   protected RECOServiceConnectListener c;
   private long l;
   private long m;
   private boolean n = false;
   private boolean o = true;
   private boolean p = true;
   private int q;
   private ServiceConnection r = new c(this);

   private RECOBeaconManager(Context var1) {        /some code/    }
   public static RECOBeaconManager getInstance(Context var0) {        /some code/    }
   @Deprecated
   public static RECOBeaconManager getInstance(Context var0, boolean var1) {        /some code/    }
   public static RECOBeaconManager getInstance(Context var0, boolean var1, boolean var2) {        /some code/       }

   private boolean a() {        /some code/    }
   private boolean b() {        /some code/    }
   public void bind(RECOServiceConnectListener var1) {
      ++this.q;
      this.c = var1;
      if(this.isBound()) {
          this.c();
      } else {
          if(this.q == 1) {
              Intent var2 = new Intent(this.g, RECOBeaconService.class);
              if(!this.g.bindService(var2, this.r, 1)) {
                  this.c.onServiceFail(RECOErrorCode.RECO_MANAGER_NOT_BIND);
              }
          }

      }
   }

   public void unbind() throws RemoteException {        /some code/    }
   public boolean isBound() {        /some code/    }
   public boolean isMonitoringAvailable() {        /some code/    }
   public boolean isRangingAvailable() {       /some code/    }
   public void startMonitoringForRegion(RECOBeaconRegion var1) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException {
      this.a(true);
      if(var1 == null) {
          this.a.monitoringDidFailForRegion(var1, RECOErrorCode.RECO_NULL_REGION);
          throw new NullPointerException("Cannot monitor null RECOBeaconRegion.");
      } else {
          this.j.remove(var1);
          this.j.add(var1);
          z.a(this.h, this.i, 1, new f(var1, this.l, this.m));
      }
   }

   public void stopMonitoringForRegion(RECOBeaconRegion var1) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException {       /some code/    }

   public void startRangingBeaconsInRegion(RECOBeaconRegion var1) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException {        /some code/    }
   public void stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(RECOBeaconRegion var1) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException {        /some code/    }
   public void requestStateForRegion(RECOBeaconRegion var1) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException {  /some code/    }
   private void a(boolean var1) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException {        /some code/    }
   public ArrayList<RECOBeaconRegion> getMonitoredRegions() {        /some code/    }
   public ArrayList<RECOBeaconRegion> getRangedRegions() {        /some code/    }
   public void setMonitoringListener(RECOMonitoringListener var1) {        /some code/    }
   public void setRangingListener(RECORangingListener var1) {      /some code/    }
   public void setScanPeriod(long var1) {        /some code/    }
   public void setSleepPeriod(long var1) {        /some code/    }
   private void c() {        /some code/    }
   public void setDiscontinuousScan(boolean var1) {       /some code/    }
   public String version() {        /some code/    }
   static {        /some code/     }
}
```

First, in bind method, RECOServiceConnectListener is an interface but I can't find the implementation in this class. Is it possible? The interface consists of an abstract method and constant. Do they need implementing in the class?

Second, in startMonitoringForRegion method,

```
 z.a(this.h, this.i, 1, new f(var1, this.l, this.m));
```

I can't fine z in this class. It is only mentioned as an import. The z class exists. The other class like RECOMonitoringListener is defined and used. but the z is not. Am I wrong?

Please give me some idea to how can I analyze this code. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your code would be a *lot* more readable if you didn't just use single-letter variable names. Are you sure this isn't decompiled obfuscated code?

Comment: As far as I can understand , The z exist it just in different package , go to import line of z and navigate to that directory as it is specified , (This would be in Project Explorer in eclipse/Android) for example if import line is com.example.something.z , go to com.example.something directory and look there

Comment: @JonSkeet  Skeet Thanks but this is code from company API. I can't translate this code, so I can't rename.

Comment: @L-X Thanks you for your advice but I can't find another package, but your advice will be very helpful for near my programming.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't translate this code"? Is this what the *real* code looks like, that you have to work with?

Comment: @JonSkeet I was work in this code just the company give us some annotation like
[code]//Write the code when the state of the monitored region is changed
but Now I want know how was the other method was working, that is translate code(interpretation is more relevant).

Comment: I suggest you find out more about the origin of this then - because it looks like it's the result of decompiling obfuscated code, which will be *horrible* to work with compared with the original. It may be the source of your problem, too...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for confuse you. But thanks to give advice to me.

Answer (score 0):

RECOBeaconManager does not implement RECOServiceConnectListener. Thus it does not need to implement (or redefine as you call it) the methods of RECOServiceConnectListener.

As for z no idea. It does not appear at all in the code you posted. And RECOBeaconManager does not extend or implement anything so it cannot come from a superclass. It must be an import but from your posted code it is not possible to know anything about it.

If you were using an IDE, like Netbeans in example, you could SHIFT+CLICK on z and it would take you to its definition.

Comment: You said RECOBeaconManager does not implement RECOServiceConnectListener, but they used RECOServiceConnectListener by type which variable named var1 and c. Am I wrong please give some advice for understanding java